# How do I fit a line in a histogram plot and measure the slope?

Tags: python, histogram, linear-regression

Good day. Please I need help fitting a line on a portion of the plots. I want a line fitted on the steep towards the right.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize =(12,5))
ax[0].hist(pfd.peak_flux.loc[pfd.peak_flux<=1], bins = 30, color='grey', histtype = 'step')
ax[0].set_xlabel('Peak flux density')
ax[0].set_ylabel(r'$log N$')
ax[0].set_yscale('log')
ax[0].set_xscale('log')

ax[1].hist(pfd.int_flux.loc[pfd.int_flux<=1], bins = 30, color='grey', histtype = 'step')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Integrated flux density')
ax[1].set_ylabel(r'$log N$')
ax[1].set_yscale('log')
ax[1].set_xscale('log')
#ax[1].set_ylabel('counts')
#plt.title(r'MGPS positional error for $\leq 2$ arc-seconds')
plt.savefig('log-fluxes.png', dpi = 700, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

Here is how the plot looks?

[image: hist_plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data points of histogram as bellow :

```
counts, bins, bars =ax[0].hist(np.random.randn(1000,1), bins = 30, color='grey', histtype = 'step')
```

counts is y axis and bins is x axis. Use regression from scipy to get the slop of last n points.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
Regression=linregress(counts[-15:], bins[-15:])
slope=Regression.slope
```